# Get the online users in my spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to get how manyusers are currently using my application, one problem is everytime a user make a request my application create a new token for that user (react get that token and replace the old one)

I already tried SessionRegistry but because it create a new token for each request the number it returns increase everytime:

```
   @Autowired
   private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

   @GetMapping
   public ResponseEntity<Response<Integer>> getSessions(){

       List<String> userDetailsList = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().stream()
               .filter(u -> !sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(u, false).isEmpty())
               .map(Object::toString)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
       int sessions = userDetailsList.size();
               //MySessionListener.getActiveSessions();
       Response<Integer> response = new Response<>();
       response.setData(sessions);
       return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
   }
```

in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterImpl:

```
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   
    http.httpBasic().and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/swagger-ui/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable();

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

    http.addFilterBefore(
        authenticationTokenFilterBean(), 
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
    );

    http
       .headers().cacheControl();

    http
       .sessionManagement()
       .maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
}
```

in my class who implements OncePerRequestFilter has this method to update the crrent token for each request so i don't know if this will be a problem:

```
     if (jwtTokenUtil.canTokenBeRefreshed(authToken)) {
                                authToken = jwtTokenUtil.refreshToken(authToken);
                            }
 request.setAttribute("x-auth", authToken);
```

ps:
My current application is deployed in a wildfly 18 server and the requestes are handled by apache

Comment: Since your session policy is STATELESS, you cannot get active sessions(online users).
You are not maintaining any session information in your back-end, state information comes together with request(token in your case).
Probably you should use WebSocket or some other technologies to maintain user activity status

Comment: @I.Yuldoshev thanks for the answer the main problem is i refresh the token for each request the user does, so do you have any solution how to keep track? If so i can remove the stateless but i don't know how to procede